# SQL Select only the newest item

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to read out some values from my database.
What i would like to see is an readout with the newest value from an item. My system is based on an log. And i would like to display the latest log on an screen.

[image: Screenshot of the Table]

*Blue = What it displays
/// Red = What i would like to see*

**My current SQL query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM log WHERE active = '1' GROUP by name ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
```

**My current output:**

```
id  name    nickname    speed   height  battery lat lng type    pilot   time_stamp Descending 1 active  
35  Falon 2     Falon 2     0   0   0   34.000000   12.000000   bird    Falon 2     2018-06-18 11:44:37     1
33  Falon 1     Falon 1     0   0   0   3.000000    8.000000    bird    Falon 1     2018-06-18 11:37:44     1
```

So it does select only one item (because of the DISTINCT. But it displays the oldest value. What i would like to see is Falcon 1, and Falcon 2. But sorted on time_stamp.

What i tried is to change **DESC to ASC** but it only changes the readout by name.

I'm using MySQL (MariaDB) with PHPmyAdmin to display and execute the commands.

Comment: Could you add your **Desired Output**?

Answer (score 2):

Your query makes no sense.  You are using `select *` with `group by`, so you have many columns that are not being aggregated.  This wouldn't work in most databases, not even in the more recent versions of MySQL (based on the default settings).

The `select distinct` doesn't do anying.

You want to filter the data, so use `where`:

```
select l.*
from log l
where l.time_stamp = (select max(l2.timestamp)
                      from log l2
                      where l2.active = 1 and l2.name = l.name
                     );
```

Note that I removed the single quotes around `'1'`.  Presumably `active` is a number and the comparison should be to a number (if the `active` is a string, then use the single quotes!).

Comment: Yes this works. However it only displays ONE bird (Falon 1). And it should be displaying Falon 2 to.

Comment: @JorisAkkermans . . . Correlate the subquery with whatever your definition of "item" is.  This is not clear in your question.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB 10.2 supports *Windowed Aggregates*:

```
WITH cte AS
 ( SELECT *,
      -- assign a row number per name, newest row first
      row_number() over (partition by name ORDER BY time_stamp DESC) as rn
   FROM log 
   WHERE active = '1'
 )
select * from cte
where rn = 1 -- return the latest row per name
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the usage of `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT` will ensure that you only get one copy of a row with the exact same details. Which will never be the case as every row has a different `id` value.

The command you are looking for is `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE active = '1' GROUP by name ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

`LIMIT` is only showing the number of rows between the offset (0) and the number of rows to return (1). IF you're not arsed about pagination, you can just specify the number of rows to return: `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: That might be it. The problem right now i'm facing to is that with the LIMIT option it only displays One Bird. But i would like to display every bird with an unique name.

Comment: Yes, but it displays only the one with old timestamp date.

Answer (score 0):

Select * has unpredictable results with group by, you can't be sure which timestamp field it will choose for each group.

You need to add

> group by name, timestamp

Then you can use order by.

However, if you just want one for each group you could remove the order by and add

> group by name, timestamp having timestamp=max(timestamp)